# C# Linq RemoveAll with dynamic OR statement

Tags: c#, linq, removeall

I need to know if there is a way to create this part dynamically. Or, is it even possible? Using "Contians" will not work in this situation.

```
(x.Letter!= "a") && (x.Letter!= "b") && (x.Letter!= "e")
```

The "a", "b", "c" will be generated out of a ListBox using a for loop. There can be any number of items in the list box. That is why this must be dynamic.

```
MyList.RemoveAll(x => (x.Letter != "a") && (x.Letter!= "b") && (x.Letter!= "e"));
```

Comment: Why can `Contains` not be used?

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to achieve, but here is a (simple) suggestion: Put any values (strings?) you get from the listbox(es) into a `HashSet` (or a similar type of collection that allows quick lookups). Then you can do something like `MyList.RemoveAll(x => !mysHashSet.Contains(x.Letter));`

Comment: @nbokmans - I can not use "Contains" because it does what it means. If I have a list that is made up of: "A", "AA", "AAA", "AAAA" and I only want to remove "A", "Contains" will remove all of them. That is not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to make it dynamic, because the structure of your condition is very regular: you check containment against all items. Hence you can do it like this:

```
var check = new List<string>(itemsFromListBox);
MyList.RemoveAll(x => check.All(s => x.Letter != s));
```

Comment: So far with the short tests i have done, this is working exactly the way I need it to. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to make sure that nothing in that list is equal to `x.Letter`, so I'd construct the list of values you'd like to remove first, then use that.

I don't know what your `ListBox` looks like, but let's assume you can get the list of strings out of it like this:

```
List<string> stuffToRemove = myListBox.Items.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

You should just be able to use that list of strings in your LINQ statement:

```
MyList.RemoveAll(x => stuffToRemove.Contains(x.Letter));
```

---

If you actually intended to *keep* the stuff in the `ListBox`, then adjust it accordingly:

```
List<string> stuffToKeep = myListBox.Items.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

MyList.RemoveAll(x => !stuffToKeep.Contains(x.Letter));
```